# How do I get the day, month, year, and time to show in my @Html.EditorFor

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to attach the time next to the date for users to put the date and time of when they've joined and left. I attached a photo of what the page looks like and where I'd like the time to show.
[site example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umdRR.png)

```
namespace TheatreCMS3.Areas.Blog.Models
{
    public class BlogAuthor
    {
        public int BlogAuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Bio { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy/MM/dd HHmmss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Joined { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Left { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my model. This is what I've recently tried but it had no effect on the view.

Here is my view:

```
<div class="flex-container">
            
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Joined, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 general joinedLabel" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Joined, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control joined" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Joined, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Left, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2 general" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Left, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control left" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Left, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of the view?

Comment: I just updated my post!

Comment: There are only so many supported `<input type="..."/>`. What about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local ? Though you would probably be better off with separate date / time controls.